# jQuery doesn;t work after .slideUp

Tags: jquery

I have a Menu which collapses for smartphones and tablets:

```
<nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#tf-home" class="page-scroll"><img class="toplogo" src="img/logotop.png" alt="Top Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <a id="menuButton" href="#">Menu</a>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#tf-home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-about" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-team" class="page-scroll">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-services" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-works" class="page-scroll">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-testimonials" class="page-scroll">References</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I wanted to use jQuery to slide up the collapsable Menu when user cliks on any of the links from the collapsable menu. It works fine **but only once**! After that, if I click on a Menu it doesn't open anymore!? What is it that I am missing?

Here is jQuery code:

function main() {

(function () {
   'use strict';

/* ==============================================
    Testimonial Slider
    =============================================== */

```
$('a.page-scroll').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
        }, 900);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

/*====================================
Show Menu on Book
======================================*/
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = $(window).height() - 600; /* This value was 200 but it was causing problems in different resolutions. */
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('on');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('on');
    }
});

$(function(){
    $(".navbar-nav a, #menuButton").click(function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").slideToggle();
    });
});

$('body').scrollspy({ 
    target: '.navbar-default',
    offset: 80
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#team").owlCarousel({

      navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      autoHeight : true,
      itemsCustom : [
                    [0, 1],
                    [450, 2],
                    [600, 2],
                    [700, 2],
                    [1000, 4],
                    [1200, 4],
                    [1400, 4],
                    [1600, 4]
                  ],
  });

  $("#clients").owlCarousel({

      navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      autoHeight : true,
      itemsCustom : [
                    [0, 1],
                    [450, 2],
                    [600, 2],
                    [700, 2],
                    [1000, 4],
                    [1200, 5],
                    [1400, 5],
                    [1600, 5]
                  ],
  });

  $("#testimonial").owlCarousel({
    navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem:true
    });

});

/*====================================
Portfolio Isotope Filter
======================================*/
$(window).load(function() {
    var $container = $('#lightbox');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });
    $('.cat a').click(function() {
        $('.cat .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

}());

}
main();

Comment: You told it to slide up, but did you tell it to slide down?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `slideToggle()` instead of `slideUp()`

Comment: I tried slideToggle but it doesn't work?

Comment: @Populus: What should I add exactly?

Comment: "if I click on a Menu it doesn't open anymore!". How do you click on a hidden element?

Comment: But I didn't use .hide in my jquery, just .slideUp

Comment: `slideUp` hides the element.

Comment: Permanently? I didn't know that. So how do I make it 'visible'?

Comment: Yes, permanently. I'm really  interested to know what you expected it to do. Add a child `a` or `button` to the `div` element. Add a click listener to the added child node and then hide/show the `ul` on the click event.

Comment: As a suggestion, do not use the stupid/heavy bootstrap framework, stupid frameworks have lots of styles that prevent you from easily customizing a feature.

Answer (score 0):

your

```
<a href="#" id="showMEnu">showMenu</a>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#tf-home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-about" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-team" class="page-scroll">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-services" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-works" class="page-scroll">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-testimonials" class="page-scroll">References</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

will collapse entirely.. so there is nothing to click on anymore
try this..

```
$("#showMEnu").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").slideDown();
});
```

Comment: It does slide down. What I want is to slide up and closes when I click on an item in a collapsable menu

Comment: $("#showMEnu").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").slideToggle();
});

Comment: "What I want is to slide up and close" .. when it slides up.. it is close .. it is like when you set display:none

Comment: show us the whole code, the error should be somewhere else

Comment: I suggest to work with id's instead of classes when it comes to display/hide (slideUp/Down) .. in some cases the classes are overwritten

Comment: you have a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu button, then also bind it to the event that uses `slideToggle`

I think that's what you wanted.

**HTML**

```
<a id="menuButton" href="#">Menu</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#tf-home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-about" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-team" class="page-scroll">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-services" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-works" class="page-scroll">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-testimonials" class="page-scroll">References</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tf-contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".navbar-nav a, #menuButton").click(function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Make sure you place the menu button outside of the menu container `.navbar-collapse`

Working jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ufa9107r/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you said. It still doesn't work. Just once.

Comment: Are you sure? It works exactly as expected in the fiddle. I guess I don't understand what you mean by _just once_. If you look at the fiddle, it doesn't matter how many times you click the menu button, it toggles the display. Also, since we bound the links within the menu, it closes every time you choose a link.

Comment: Yes, I tried everything three ties already and it works just once.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what you wanted

```
$(function(){
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").slideToggle();
});
});

$(function(){
$(".navbar-nav a").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").slideUp();
});
});
```

Comment: what happens when you click on the toggleNavigation-Button?

Comment: It normally opens the menu and when I click the menu it closes it. But just for one time. When I try to open the menu again it doesn't work.

Comment: does it work on jsfiddle? .. do you have further javescript-code?

Comment: what else jQuery do you have?

Comment: I updated jQuery code at the top. Thanks for patience!